# multiple if statement with javascript in html input

Tags: javascript, php, html, if-statement

I want to execute specific javascript if $_post['value'] larger than 100 and another javascript if $_post['value'] smaller than 100

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    if (document.getElementById("user_amount") > 100) {
        function euroConverter() {
            document.amount.value = document.user_amount.value - (document.user_amount.value * 0.08)
        }
    }

    if (document.getElementById("user_amount") < 100) {
        function euroConverter() {
            document.amount.value = document.user_amount.value - (document.user_amount.value * 0.1)
        }
    }
</script>
```

and html

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
    <input type="number" id="user_amount" class="form-control" name="user_amount" onChange="euroConverter()">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group input-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount" onChange="dollarConverter()">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear, in my opinion in the code you share there are a series of inconsistencies that are not clearly linked to your concern. I recommend you edit your question to explain more clearly the problem and help you better

Comment: simply i want to execute a javascript when $_POST['value'] is larger than 100 and execute another javascript when $_POST['value'] is smaller than 100 with if statement

Comment: $_POST['value'] is a vlaue which i get from form with input :
    <input type="number" id="user_amount" name="user_amount" onChange="euroConverter()">

Comment: $_POST in PHP refers to an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method, in your example you do not show any php code, you are getting access to input values using javascript getElementById method. Thats why I commented out that there are some missed logic

Comment: If what you need is an if logic with the inputs values using only js please take a look to this example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oPBLjj?editors=0010

Comment: Thanks for trying to help .. i want to get value in : `<input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount" >` when i put values in `<input type="number" id="user_amount" name="user_amount" onChange="euroConverter()">` ... ex : i put 90 in user_amount i get 81 in amount input

Answer (score 0):

As user615274 said that $_POST value is a PHP value In JavaScript pretty much most of the items are objects. First of all you are missing your closing input tag in your HTML. Second we declare the variable using var you don't have that for example var name = ‘billy’; document.write(name.toLowerCase()); Also you Need and fix your logic as well!

Comment: sorry my javascript skills is not good thanks for helping i want to get value in : <input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount" > when i put values in <input type="number" id="user_amount" name="user_amount" onChange="euroConverter()"> ... ex : i put 90 in user_amount i get 81 in amount input